# VScode autocomplete not working after using sshfs to mount a directory inside the workspace

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, intellisense, sshfs

I’m using VScode to develop a Django web application on the next environment:

•   OS and Version: Windows 10

•   VS Code Version: 1.52.2

•   Python Extension Version: v2021.5.842923320

•   Remote – SSH Version: v0.65.4

From my Windows laptop, I work on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM using the Remote – SSH plugin, So I have configured a python3.9 virtual environment with Django3.2 and others python packages. Also, I have pylint installed and all works as expected.

The issue arises when I mount a folder inside the application media folder (inside the workspace) from another station through sshfs. What happens is that autocomplete stops working and when y press Clr+Space I just get a loading message.

Note that this folder that I mount through sshfs is very big more than 1 TB with many files including python scripts and also I note that even when I close the VScode I cannot unmount this folder because the fusermount said that the folder is used by some process (I guess is the VScode process inside the VM). After all, if I don’t open the VScode I'm able to mount and unmount this folder without a problem.

I have also excluded this media folder using the "files.exclude" and "files.watcherExclude" but the issue persists.

There is someone who has had this issue before or some similar problem. I would appreciate any suggestions.

[Update]
Even using `files.exclude`, `serach.exclude` or not, the Intellisence works fine for a while if I mount the folder after open VScode. But if I close and reopen the Vscode the intellisence stops work. The same issue if I mount the folder before open the VScode.

[Update2]
[Python language sever OUTPUT panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AToq.png)

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

creating a "pyrightconfig.json" at the root of the workspace, and adding the exclude solve the issue https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#main-pyright-config-options

```
{"exclude": ["**/application/media"]}
```

Comment: @Steven, the issue was fixed with this. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should take `search.exclude` instead of `files.exclude`.

```
  // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in fulltext searches and quick open. Inherits all glob patterns from the `files.exclude` setting.
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/*.code-search": true
  },

  // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders. For example, the file Explorer decides which files and folders to show or hide based on this setting. Refer to the `search.exclude` setting to define search specific excludes.
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
  },
```

The [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

**Update:**

Which Language Server are you using? `Pylance`?, `Jedi`?. Could you try to switch the Language Server?

And could you have a look at these panles?

[image]

**Update2:**

Can you try to upgrade the Python extension? And if it doesn't work, can you try to downgrade the node version to 12? You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1392).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn’t work. The issue persists. I already knew about `search.exclude` but as I understand this option inherits all the paths specified on `files.exclude`. that’s why I thought that just use `files.exclude` for this could be enough. I putted an update end what really is happening

Comment: @Javier hi, could you look into the update?

Comment: I'm using Pylance, and I get an error on the output panle for Python Language Server. I will share it on top question.

Comment: I don't have the VS IntelliCode entry like you. I will try to switch to Jedi? I realy appreciate you help on this. Thanks!

Comment: @Javier Can you try to downgraded Pylance to 2021.5.4? And it should be fixed in the next version. You can refer to here:https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1397.

Comment: It was not solved with the Pylance downgraded and also I tried with Jedi and the issue persist. this is driving me insane, because when I mount another folder that contain a few data , everything works fine. The problem is with that huge folder.

Comment: @Javier hi, can you have a look at the update?

Comment: @Javier Hi friend, have you solved the problem?

Comment: Hi, no, I'm working without mount this folder. Seems to me that the issue is more releate with some specific type of files inside that folder than the amount of files. After investigating and investigating and not finding a solution I have already given up